# problem getting while displaying Dropdown list box values in asp,net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am getting following error when I am assing the Dropdown list box values..

`DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'code'`.

Here is my dropdown list box code in my view.

```
<span id="StateFilterRow"> State: <%= Html.DropDownList("StatesFilter", new SelectList(Model.StatesList, "code", "code", Model.SelectedState), new { style = "background-color: #eee; font-weight:bold;" })%></span>
```

here is my Code to get the Dropdown list box values.

in my result States I have text and value for States

```
  Text  = '{code = AL}'
```

in my ViewModel..

```
  public SelectList StatesList { get; set; }
```

is that something I am doing wrong in my view code?

can anybody help me out

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getListOfStates` method already returns a `SelectList`, so in your view you don't need to create yet another one. So you could modify this method and specify the properties there:

```
private SelectList getListOfStates()
{
    var values = 
        from s in generic.CodeTypes
        join c in generic.ApplicationCodes on s.CodeType_Id equals c.CodeType_ID
        where s.CodeType_Id == 26
        select new
        {
            Code = c.Code,
        };
    return new SelectList(values, "Code", "Code");
}
```

and then in your view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "StatesFilter", 
    Model.StatesList, 
    new { style = "background-color: #eee; font-weight:bold;" }
) %>
```

Comment: Then How to call this SelectedList  ViewModel.stateList = getListOfStates(); I am getting error here..

Comment: @kumar, what kind of error are you getting? Could you be a little more specific please?

Comment: Object referece not set to an instact of an object Error Darin.thanks

Comment: @kumar, which object is null? Is it inside the `getListOfStates` method? Please POST your entire action code.

Comment: yes this getListOfStates its saying object reference error Darin. the code which I have is GetListofStates and ViewModel.StateList = getListOfStates();

Comment: @kumar, so then fix this method. I mean was it even working before?

Comment: yes its working before but after  you sujjested the code which is not working in this codition.. thanks

Comment: @kumar, which object/property is null?

Comment: Darin, Please can you tell me how to display SeletedState value in the dropdown list box? be its allways displaying all the states even in the edit mode I am not getting alredy has state value.

Comment: @kumar, personally I would use strongly typed helper `DropDownListFor` instead of `DropDownList` and would simply set the corresponding property in my controller action to the desired value. In your case you need to set `ViewData["StatesFilter"] = "1"` to set the selected value of the dropdown (`1` need to be present as value in your ddl).